# E/protractor - Could not find Angular on page http://localhost:8080/ : retries looking for angular exceeded

Tags: angularjs, protractor

Pues este es el error que me sale cuando ejecuto protractor:

***Failed: Angular could not be found on the page http://localhost:8080/. If this is not an Angular application, you may need to turn off waiting for Angular.***

Lo único que he hecho es cambiar de versiones de node a la 7 , e instalar protractor y phantomjs , y cuando ejecuto el comando protractor tests/tests.js me salta dicho error.

**tests.js:**

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    chromeOnly: true,
    specs: ["e2e/TC01-loadFilm.js"]

};
```

AngularJS y Bootstrap está instalado en una carpeta /public , tanto mi carpeta /public como /tests está en la raíz del proyecto , no sé si será ese el problema.

Comment: En SO en inglés hay un problema parecido, y parece que tiene que ver con el encoding de la página Index. Tal vez pueda ser algo semejante (al menos el escenario es parecido)...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31752301/protractor-error-angular-could-not-be-found-on-the-page

Comment: Según el error creo que debes comprobar si son compatibles las versiones de la node y si se ha eliminado algo importante

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He recopilado algo de información y parece que hay dos posibles soluciones. La más sencilla es añadir `ng-app` en tu etiqueta body de la siguiente manera:

`<body ng-app>`

Eso le daría a entender a protractor que esta en un proyecto de angular.

La otra solución sería añadir en el root del typescript en la configuración de tu aplicación la ruta del typescript de node_modules de la siguiente manera:

```
"typeRoots": [
   "../node_modules/@types"
]
```

esto iría en el fichero `tsconfig.e2e.json`

Comment: Muchas gracias por el interés ,ya funciona